# Sharing Acme configuration for multiple Traefik services

Tags: ssl, traefik, lets-encrypt

I have a server running Docker containers with Traefik. Let's say the machine's hostname is `machine1.example.com`, and each service runs as a subdomain, e.g. `srv1.machine1.example.com`, `srv2.machine1.example.com`, `srv3.machine1.example.com`....

I want to have LetsEncrypt generate a Wildcard certificate for `*.machine1.example.com` and use it for all of the services instead of generating a separate certificate for each service.

The annoyance is that I have to put the configuration lines into every single service's `labels`:

```
labels:
  - traefik.http.routers.srv1.rule=Host(`srv1.machine1.example.com`)
  - traefik.http.routers.srv1.tls=true
  - traefik.http.routers.srv1.tls.certresolver=myresolver
  - traefik.http.routers.srv1.tls.domains[0].main=machine1.example.com
  - traefik.http.routers.srv1.tls.domains[0].sans=*.machine1.example.com

labels:
  - traefik.http.routers.srv2.rule=Host(`srv2.machine1.example.com`)
  - traefik.http.routers.srv2.tls=true
  - traefik.http.routers.srv2.tls.certresolver=myresolver
  - traefik.http.routers.srv2.tls.domains[0].main=machine1.example.com
  - traefik.http.routers.srv2.tls.domains[0].sans=*.machine1.example.com

# etc.
```

This gets to be a lot of seemingly-needless boilerplate.

I tried work around it (in a way that is still ugly and annoying, but less so) by using the templating feature in the file provider like this:

```
[http]
  [http.routers]

  {{ range $i, $e := list "srv1" "srv2 }}
    [http.routers."{{ $e }}".tls]
      certResolver = "letsencrypt"
      [[http.routers."{{ $e }}".tls.domains]]
        main = "machine1.example.com"
        sans = ["*.machine1.example.com"]
  {{ end }}
```

That did not work because the routers created here are `srv1@file`, `srv2@file` instead of `srv1@docker`, `srv2@docker` which are created by the docker-compose configuration.

Is there any way to specify this configuration only once and have it apply to multiple services?

Answer (score -1):

At present the support for multiple replicas sharing the same storage is a money-grab and thus not supported as per the warning in [ACME storage](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/#storage) which states

> For concurrency reasons, this file cannot be shared across multiple instances of Traefik.

One suggestion depending on your situation is to actually manage the SSL certificates and deploy the file as needed.  However, weigh that with the cost of the enterprise edition of Traefik where the price isn't shown on their website last I checked.

Comment: This question isn't about multiple replicas sharing a certificate, it's about multiple sites _on one server_ sharing the same certificate, which _can_ be done in the community edition - it just takes a lot of repetitive configuration.